# py3DNS, validate_email function give 'TimeoutError: Timeout'

Tags: python, data-cleaning, email-validation

validate_email function give 'TimeoutError: Timeout' message after <100 rows been executed from my df.

> ```
> from validate_email import validate_email
> for i in range(0,len(df)):
>     df['is_valid_email'].iloc[i]= validate_email(df['Emails'].iloc[i],verify=True)
> ```

Comment: For now i just use the Try and Except function to ignore the error and skip to next row. but still not a good practice

Comment: Please provide a [mre].